# ACCESS 2000: queries "chain" too slow with added "WHERE" clause

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

**PREMISE**

I have to modify a very old Access 2000 database.
What i have are two tables:

> **Products** table:
>
> - **pID as Text** - this is the Key Field (yes, is Text, nothing i can do about it)
> - **pLevel as Integer** - this is the Product Level: 0=Finished, 1 to 7=Sub-Product
> - **pDescription as text** - Just a description
>
> **P-Association** table:
>
> - **pIDParent as Text**
> - **pIDChild as Text**

What this table do is an association between a (sub)product and other subproduct.
The "rule" is that pIDChild level must be higher that the pIDParent level.

Then there's a Form that shows all the childs of a given pID. This is based on a "chain" of queries:

This is the query q-pAssociation0, which looks at the selected product and returns the childs:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [t-Associations].pIDParent, [t-Associations].pIDChild, [t-Products].pLevel AS pParentLevel, [t-Products].pLevel AS pChildLevel FROM [t-Products] INNER JOIN [t-Associations] ON [t-Products].pID = [t-Associations].pIDChild
WHERE ((([t-Associations].pIDParent)=[Forms]![fTreeProdotti]![txtProdID]));
```

then there's 7 queries *(q-pAssociation1~q-pAssociation7)*, each one working on the previous one.
Here's the q-pAssociation1:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [q-pAssociation0].pIDChild AS pIDParent, [t-Associations].pIDChild, [q-pAssociation0].pChildLevel AS pParentLevel, [t-Products].pLevel AS pChildLevel FROM [q-pAssociation0] INNER JOIN ([t-Products] INNER JOIN [t-Associations] ON [t-Products].pID = [t-Associations].pIDChild) ON [q-pAssociation0].pIDChild = [t-Associations].pIDParent;
```

In the end, there's a GROUP query that groups all the previous ones and on which the form is based.

**QUESTION**
I have to modify this all so the queries returns only the Childs with Level = parent level+1 (so, if a Parent has a Child 2 level "down" or more it does not have to be returned.

So, i added a condition in each query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [q-pAssociation0].pIDChild AS pIDParent, [t-Associations].pIDChild, [q-pAssociation0].pChildLevel AS pParentLevel, [t-Products].pLevel AS pChildLevel
FROM [q-pAssociation0] INNER JOIN ([t-Products] INNER JOIN [t-Associations] ON [t-Products].pID = [t-Associations].pIDChild) ON [q-pAssociation0].pIDChild = [t-Associations].pIDParent
WHERE ((([t-Products].pLevel)=[q-pAssociation0]![pParentLevel]+1));
```

But now the q-pAssociation7 needs 10 minutes to return about 15 records, while without the "WHERE" condition it return about 25 records almost immediatly.

How can i obtain only the product which are just one level down without having this slow query?

Comment: Is `[t-Products].pLevel` indexed?

Comment: No. Is this the problem? (sorry, not very fond on what it changes.....)

Comment: OH, if this matters, the tables are linked, they "physically" stays in another MDB file.

Comment: Try changing the `Indexed` property of that field from `No` to `Yes (Duplicates OK)` and see if that helps speed things up. (You'll have to make that change in the .mdb file where the tables actually reside.)

Comment: It doesnt change.
q-pAssociation4 still needs 10s to return results (no matter if 0 or 20 records). For the next queries (q-pAssociation5,6,7) times increases... i'd say exponentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it might help if you created a query that isolated all of the Associations that are one Level apart...

```
SELECT a.pIDParent, a.pIDChild, tP.pLevel AS pParentLevel, tC.pLevel AS pChildLevel
FROM ([t-Associations] AS a INNER JOIN [t-Products] AS tP ON a.pIDParent = tP.pID) 
    INNER JOIN [t-Products] AS tC ON a.pIDChild = tC.pID
WHERE (((tC.pLevel)=[tP].[pLevel]+1));
```

...save that as [q-one_level_down], and then use that in your queries so you don't have to keep (explicitly) referring back to the Products table to get the Levels.

If you do that then your [q-pAssociation0] query becomes...

```
SELECT [q-one_level_down].pIDParent, [q-one_level_down].pIDChild, 
    [q-one_level_down].pParentLevel, [q-one_level_down].pChildLevel
FROM [q-one_level_down]
WHERE ((([q-one_level_down].pIDParent)=[Forms]![fTreeProdotti]![txtProdID]));
```

... and (I believe) your [q-pAssociation1] query becomes

```
SELECT [q-one_level_down].pIDParent, [q-one_level_down].pIDChild, 
    [q-one_level_down].pParentLevel, [q-one_level_down].pChildLevel
FROM [q-pAssociation0__NEW_] INNER JOIN [q-one_level_down] 
    ON ([q-pAssociation0__NEW_].pChildLevel = [q-one_level_down].pParentLevel) 
        AND ([q-pAssociation0__NEW_].pIDChild = [q-one_level_down].pIDParent);
```

If this approach gives you the desired results but you still find it too slow, then the next refinement would be to use an Append query to persist the results of [q-one_level_down] in a local table that has all four columns indexed, and then use that. (In that case you may want to name it [lt-one_level_down] -- "lt" for "local table" -- to avoid confusion.)